# Match BINARY datatype against binary pattern in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching, match

Assume a `BINARY` column with the following values:

```
1001001
0101001
1110110
1101101
```

What's the most efficient way to match against a binary pattern?
Any non-regular-expression approaches come to mind?

```
*1*1**1
```

Matched values from example above:

```
0101001
1101101
```

Comment: Your input values are of fixed length ?

Comment: All values are fixed length. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat it as a binary number, then use Boolean operations.

```
mysql> SELECT CONV('0101001', 2, 10) & b'0101001' = b'0101001';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| CONV('0101001', 2, 10) & b'0101001' = b'0101001' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                1 | -- means TRUE
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONV('0000000', 2, 10) & b'0101001' = b'0101001';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| CONV('0000000', 2, 10) & b'0101001' = b'0101001' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                0 | -- means FALSE
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONV('0000111', 2, 10) & b'0101001' = b'0101001';
+--------------------------------------------------+
| CONV('0000111', 2, 10) & b'0101001' = b'0101001' |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                0 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring()` in case of fixed length values something as

```
mysql> select substring('0101001',2,1) as pos1 ,substring('0101001',4,1) pos2,substring('0101001',7,1) pos3;
+------+------+------+
| pos1 | pos2 | pos3 |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 1    | 1    |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you can use the above in the select statement as

```
select * from table_name
where
substring(col_val,2,1) = 1
and substring(col_val,4,1) = 1
and substring(col_val,7,1) = 1
```